# App Engine redirect login based on user

Tags: python, google-app-engine, redirect

I have an App Engine project where I am storing a user's email address and a specific redirect URL for that user in the datastore.

What I want to do is set the redirect destination of the login based on the user that is logging in.

```
q = Photos.all()
q.filter("email =", users.get_current_user().email())
q = db.GqlQuery("SELECT * FROM Photos " +
    "WHERE email = :1 ", users.get_current_user().email())
for p in q.run():
```

The variable `p.redirect` then gives me the URL I want that specific user to be redirected to.

Below is what I have tried but this is obviously not working because the user hasn't logged in yet so I receive the following error `AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'email'`

```
    user = users.get_current_user()

    if user:
        # User is signed in             
else:
        # User is not signed in 
        q = Photos.all()
        q.filter("email =", users.get_current_user().email())
        q = db.GqlQuery("SELECT * FROM Photos " +
            "WHERE email = :1 ", users.get_current_user().email())
        for p in q.run():
            url = users.create_login_url(p.redirect)

template_values = {
    'url': url,
    }
```

Any help would be appreciated. I've only been working with Python & App Engine for a couple of days so I may be missing something very obvious.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've worked around this by adding a new redirect handler, so the login redirect is now `url = users.create_login_url('/authorise')`

Within `/authorise` I run the GQL query and pass the user onto their destination.

It works, although I'd be interested to know if there is a more efficient approach.

Answer (score 1):

Mark your resource (example: /photos) as login:required in app.yaml. Appengine will then redirect the user to login page and once they completes login will come back to your resource (/photos) and at that time you will have email for the current user.

https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/python/config/appconfig#Python_app_yaml_Requiring_login_or_administrator_status

Answer (score 0):

Your `if` statement is backwards:

```
if user:
    # User is signed in             
    q = Photos.all()
    q.filter("email =", users.get_current_user().email())
    q = db.GqlQuery("SELECT * FROM Photos " +
        "WHERE email = :1 ", users.get_current_user().email())
    for p in q.run():
        url = users.create_login_url(p.redirect)
else:
    # User is not signed in
```